# Опасно ли открытие портов у сервера на линукс

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, iptables, port

Опасно ли открытие портов у севера на линукс *Debian* и чем?

Если я открыл порт командой:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 90 -j ACCEPT
```

Плохо ли это? Просто иначе не получается приложение на *websocket* на *node.js* запустить. Или можно как-то иначе, если порты открывать небезопасно?

Comment: Используйте прокси-сервер nginx. Он будет перенаправлять траффик с порта 80, на любой другой. Я перенаправляю на 3000, а этот порт слушает нода

Comment: А чем открытие портов на Linux (Debian) "опасней" открытия портов на другой OS (другом дистрибутиве)?

Comment: А почему стоит делать через прокси- сервер, значит открытые порты чем- то опасны или есть другие причины (возможно тот же 90 порт может быть закрытым у некоторых людей)?

Comment: Создание собственных правил для файервола при использовании HTTP протокола тоже самое что изобрести заново велосипед. Используйте Nginx. Он не только файервол, но и достаточно удобных load balancer для выдачи статического контента.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае открытые порты опасны тем, что по ним можно достучаться до чего-то, что может нанести вред тебе лично или другим людям. Сам по себе открытый порт (любой) не опасен ничем, если за ним не стоит какая-то служба, которой можно воспользоваться для этого.

Для примера, вот какие порты открыты у меня в роутере (щаз запинают за "все протоколы"):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это в домашней сети, есть внешний IP. Все из них по сути ведут туда же, и доступно снаружи. Постоянно ломятся какие долбоботы с характерными запросами. Но кто ж им разрешит пройти дальше :)

P.S. Хакеры-ломакеры приглашаются [сюда](http://95.31.214.51:9090).

Answer (score 2):

Любой открытый порт на любом «сервере» с любой операционной системой - потенциальная опасность.

Самый безопасный сервер - это сервер отключенный от всех сетей (локальной вычислительной и питания).

Но как же тогда не бояться открывать порты, если очень надо?

Все зависит от понимания того, что за этими портами скрывается.

Сразу простой пример для размышления:

на сервере открыт 80-й порт, и этот порт слушает веб-сервер (Apache или nginx). Предположим, что любой из этих веб-серверов доказал свою профпригодность в плане безопасности, другими словами их взломать либо очень сложно, либо нельзя.

Но вы берете и прикручиваете к веб-серверу некий движок некоего тыжпрограммиста. А движок оказывается на ваше несчастье «дырявый», и через некую дыру к вам на сервер прилетает бэкдор с помощью которого, например, спамеры разошлют миллион писем спама.

Вот и решайте, безопасно открывать порт или нет.